# how to change image illumination in opencv python

Tags: python, opencv

I am reading a image in python opencv, now I need to change the illumination on this image to be darker or lighter, what kind of method I should use to enable this?

Comment: Illumination isn't a clear concept, in this case. Could you, please, provide an example of what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: How about [gamma correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_correction)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can done this with opencv. Here is my suggestion

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img1 = cv2.imread('abc.jpg')
a = np.double(img1)
b = a + 15
img2 = np.uint8(b)
cv2.imshow("frame",img1)
cv2.imshow("frame2",img2)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Here i increased the brightness of image. If you use subtraction that will makes darker.

Comment: using this approach I have blue color artifacts at the final. But @devforfu 's solution works well.

Answer (score 34):

I know I am late, but I would suggest using ***gamma correction***.

Now what is ***gamma correction***?

I will make it clear in layman's terms:

- To display image on a screen, input voltage is needed.
- This voltage is output as light intensity.
- In perfect world, input voltage would be linear to output intensity.
- But the real screen output is close to an exponential curve, the
  exponent being ***gamma***.

Since the computer screen applies a gamma value to the image on screen, the process of applying inverse gamma to counter this effect is called ***gamma correction***.

[image]

Here is the code for the same using OpenCV 3.0.0 and python:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def adjust_gamma(image, gamma=1.0):

   invGamma = 1.0 / gamma
   table = np.array([((i / 255.0) ** invGamma) * 255
      for i in np.arange(0, 256)]).astype("uint8")

   return cv2.LUT(image, table)

x = 'C:/Users/524316/Desktop/stack/test.jpg'  #location of the image
original = cv2.imread(x, 1)
cv2.imshow('original',original)

gamma = 0.5                                   # change the value here to get different result
adjusted = adjust_gamma(original, gamma=gamma)
cv2.putText(adjusted, "g={}".format(gamma), (10, 30),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.8, (0, 0, 255), 3)
cv2.imshow("gammam image 1", adjusted)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Here is the original image:

[image]

Applying gamma of value 0.5 will yield:

[image]

Applying gamma of value 1.5 will yield:

[image]

Applying gamma of value 2.5 will yield:

[image]

Applying gamma of value 1.0 will yield the same image.

[Code was borrowed from this link](http://pyimagesearch.com/2015/10/05/opencv-gamma-correction)

Comment: Looks like the source is https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/10/05/opencv-gamma-correction/ (or maybe he took it from here :D)

Comment: @ComputerScientist Nope. Actually I took it from there. :D

Comment: It should probably be stated in the answer itself for completeness. (I'm currently using it for darkening some images, and it's working well for me.)

Comment: @ComputerScientist Done!!

Answer (score 4):

A small remark to complement Jeru Luke's answer. Be sure that both arrays are of type `np.uint8`. The `cv.LUT` function name stands for "look-up-table". It means that each pixel from the `image` is replaced with a value from the `table`.

You could convert both arrays:

```
def adjust_gamma(image, gamma=1.0):
   invGamma = 1.0 / gamma
   table = np.array([
      ((i / 255.0) ** invGamma) * 255
      for i in np.arange(0, 256)])
   return cv2.LUT(image.astype(np.uint8), table.astype(np.uint8))
```

Or make sure that an image array is casted to the valid type before passing into `adjust_gamma()` function. It is easy to convert the image into `float` while applying various transformations and forget to restore valid type before adjusting gamma.

Comment: reture value's type of cv2.imread is already np.uint8.